# clicking in WAKFU C#

Tags: c#, click, mouse, bots

i'm currently implementing an automated program that picks up herb seeds in WAKFU.
I have done a lot of research and am almost done. The only issue i have is with the mouse click. when i click the mouse on the "Harvest icon" it seems that the mouse ignores the harvest icon and presses on the ground, for which my character moves instead of harvesting

please reference this video i uploaded.

http://youtu.be/W69hKqtH9HE

The code for mouse clicking

```
        public void MouseClickLeft()
    {
        int x = Cursor.Position.X;
        int y = Cursor.Position.Y;
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, x, y, 0, 0);
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, x, y, 0, 0);
    }
    public void MouseClickRight()
    {
        int x = Cursor.Position.X;
        int y = Cursor.Position.Y;
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN, x, y, 0, 0);
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP, x, y, 0, 0);
    }

            Point point3 = new Point( points[0].X +60 , points[0].Y - 60);

        LinearSmoothMove(point3, delayt);

        MouseClickLeft();
```

Please tell me if you need any more code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a long dead question, but for those of you who stumble across this on Google later on, know this: Wakfu comes with what I can only describe as "natural defenses" against bots in the form of a "variably accelerated" camera. This results in two click on your screen to the same x and y coordinates translating into different clicks in the game.

This breaks most basic click bots.

In order to circumvent this, you'll have to take advantage of how teleportation "resets" the camera. A camera reset via teleportation can be brought about using zap portals, drago-express, or just clicking on the glowing pulsating blue circles on the ground to leave (and then re-enter) the area. These will reset your camera and allow you a base to work from when utilizing your bot.

I hope this helps future Googlers, and saves hours and hours of time and research ;)

Answer (score 0):

Additionally you can use your haven bag to reset the camera. Ctrl+H or click on haven bag icon - this will teleport you in/out (provided you're in place where your haven bag can be opened).